# Citing/Attaching unpublished papers in a Research Statement/Profile for a faculty job

Tags: application

I am a young academic and don't yet have any first author publications (several 2nd authors, though) but have several either submitted or very near being submitted. I am in a quantitative/scientific field.

My question is about whether it's OK to describe (and cite) finished research projects that are not yet published in a research statement for a faculty job. On a similar question, if the application requests copies of papers, can you attach "in process" papers?

Thanks for any opinion/experiences.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Yes!

Your task is to make the strongest possible case for your expertise as a researcher.  Your case would likely be stronger with a few first-author publications, but having compelling first-author work in the queue is certainly better than *not* having compelling first-author work in the queue.

In fact, even if you have first-author publications, your research statement *must* describe your ongoing research agenda, in specific, credible, and compelling detail.  Faculty hiring committees are just as interested in your future research plans as they are in your past research accomplishments.  Preprints and submitted papers that support that agenda are definitely appropriate.

Comment: Thank you (I don't yet have sufficient reputation to upvote). As a follow up, as a point of etiquette, should I tell the co-authors that I am sending the preprint as part of a job application?

Comment: @user9486: Yes, definitely discuss this with your coauthors.